# Why does the server receive a GET request even if I performed a POST request?

Tags: php, rest, flightphp

I'm trying to create a POST API with Flightphp. I've wrote the following code:

```
 Flight::route('GET /addProduct', function(){
  echo "GET REQUEST";
 });
 Flight::route('POST /addProduct', function(){
  echo "POST REQUEST";
  var_dump($_POST);
 });
```

If I perform with Postman a POST request, the output is "GET REQUEST" (and no $_POST variable is printed).

How can I receive a POST request? Why I send a code and the server receives another one?

Comment: When you make the request, do you have a trailing `/`? Example: `/addProduct/`. Web servers can be set to redirect all requests with trailing slashes to non-trailing slashes. When the redirect is done, it will become a GET request.

Comment: Yes, also with the `/` retuns `GET REQUEST`

Comment: The `.htaccess` is the following 
```Options -Indexes 
RewriteBase /magazzino/db/api
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]```

Comment: That's not handled by the htaccess but rather the web server settings. Are you using Apache?

Comment: I'm using "tophost.it", an italian hosting that use Apache

Comment: I would contact them and explain your issue to see if there's something they've done.

Comment: your code working fine on my side, maybe the issue in your post man request? how do your perform the post request there?

Comment: Postman request: https://image.ibb.co/fRngsS/Schermata_2018_04_18_alle_09_18_27.png